# Making a Dictionary in a static class thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary

Up until now I've been developing a `static class` in a C# library and all the methods are obviously static.  Any data that is manipulated is passed in, so this is thread-safe.  However, I am implementing a feature that requires a `Dictionary` to tally certain string IDs that will be generated differently for each thread.  Obviously using something like the following will not be thread safe because multiple threads will use the same `Dictionary` and mess up its state:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, uint> MyTallies = new Dictionary<string, uint>();
```

So what's my best option for making this thread-safe?  The way I see it, there are 3 (somewhat bad) options:

1. Make the class non-static; each thread has to create a new instance, and a new `Dictionary` can be created for each thread.  Performance hit.
2. Put a `lock` around the code using the `Dictionary`, and clear the `Dictionary` at the end of the lock.  Big performance hit.
3. Have the `Dictionary` be passed in to each method that needs it.  However this results in a `Dictionary` being passed in just for an optional feature that will not be used most of the time, so it seems like a weird thing for the calling code to have to do.  Also performance hit as the calling code has to create the `Dictionary` instance each time.

So what's my best option here, or is there another better option I haven't thought of?

EDIT: A simple use-case:

```
internal static class HtmlFormatter {
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, uint> MyTallies = new Dictionary<string, uint>();

    internal static string RenderHtml(string markdown) {
        string outputHtml = "";

        // (process markdown and render to HTML)
        // (found a heading that requires a unique ID)
        var id = generatedId;
        string unique = "";
        if (MyTallies.ContainsKey(id)) {
            // Already exists; suffix "-x" where x is count of duplicate IDs
            unique = "-" + ++MyTallies[id];
        }
        else {
            MyTallies[id] = 0;
        }
        id += unique;

        // (append id string to HTML output and continue processing)

        return outputHtml;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev Only a solution in degenerate edge cases - anything not totally trivial will never work with that one and requires code level locking.

Comment: Not quite sure what's the use case. The options you mentioned imply that the dictionary is not really needed al the time. Can you show a sample usage, i.e. who is responsible for clearing the dictionary, how it is populated and used.

Answer (score 0):

Lock access to the dictionaries. This way the methods are not multi threaded anymore - only one ever will be in a method. Look up the lock statement.

If you get more fancy, use a manual lock - multiple reader single writer may improve performance if most access is read only. It allows multiple reader locks, but only one writer at a time.

3 is not a solution at all - as the dictionary is not thread safe. Unless you use the ConcurrentDictionary or make a copy every time.

1 is not a solution as it is an architectural change. It may work - but then why is it static in the first place? There is a reason and you ask us to give advice without having the proper knowledge to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like your pre-optimising at the risk of writing overly complex code. I recommend you write the simplest most reliable code you can until you test exactly where your performance bottlenecks are.

Its normally best to avoid sharing objects or state between threads unless you really need to.

> Make the class non-static; each thread has to create a new instance,
>   and a new Dictionary can be created for each thread. Performance hit.

This is the way I would recommend. A few extra bytes for a Dictionary is negligible and may even be faster to use since the number of items in each dictionary will be less.

> Have the Dictionary be passed in to each method that needs it. However
>   this results in a Dictionary being passed in just for an optional
>   feature that will not be used most of the time, so it seems like a
>   weird thing for the calling code to have to do. Also performance hit
>   as the calling code has to create the Dictionary instance each time.

I cant tell without looking at your code but it feels like your code is doing too much. If your considering passing in variables that might not be used then you probably need to break your code into smaller components. (See the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

If at the end of all that it turns out you do need to share objects between threads then there are several [helpful patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern) and classes like the ConcurrentDictionary you can use. (thanks Eldar Dordzhiev)